# Ecommerce in android

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, caching, e-commerce

I am new to android development and now i am developing an e commerce application in android for online shopping.So far in this project i have created a shopping cart to hold articles selected by user. But every thing i have done works statically.

Now i have to communicate with the server to get updates about products and discounts.

I know how to consume webservices using json.

1.I am confused about that everytime i start my application i should communicate with server using webservice ?? or should i store the data in application when application is executed for the first time on device.

2.And what approach to store data should i follow

> I should store it in device cache or
>   I should store it in applications sqlite db

**Edit :**
get data from webservice

```
try {
            Log.v("inside webservice call ", "1");
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // Build JSON string
            Log.v("inside webservice call ", "2");
            JSONStringer JsonString = new JSONStringer().object().key("prodid")
                    .value("4057339").endObject();

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JsonString.toString());
            request.setEntity(entity);
            Log.v("data", JsonString.toString());
            Log.v("inside webservice call ", "2");
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient1.execute(request);
            Log.v("inside webservice call ", "3");
            Log.v("response code", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
                    + "");
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int) responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();
            Log.v("inside webservice call ", "4");
            results = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
            // Populate text fields
            String message = results.getString("message");
            String isvalid = results.getString("isvalid");
            Log.v("tag", message + isvalid);
            Log.v("inside webservice call ", "5");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I do this to get data from server

but unable to put this data in sqlite db please guide me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1.I am confused about that everytime i start my application i should communicate with server using webservice ?? or should i store the data in application when application is executed for the first time on device.
```

This totally depends on your requirement of the project,means if the data is going to be updated frequently then you should load it everytime,you can also load data periodically and if possible make one extra service from server that notify you for updates and you just need to check that only everytime.

For the images and other media you can store them to SDCard once and next time just check if they alreay exist then don't go for loading,this can save your process time.

```
2.And what approach to store data should i follow
```

To store the data as you are loading many specific and formatted and categoriesed information then sqlite db would be more help ful to store and retrieve data.

Comment: ok i will use sqlite bt is there any way to get data from webservice and store it in sqlite db ??

Comment: i dont know any SPECIALIZED FUNCTION in Android for that..i do that mannually by parsing the response and adding it into the DB. yeh for better practice you can make your own custom abstract classes to do that.

Comment: ok can you please show me the code segment of parsing the response and adding it into the DB ??

Comment: I and many other developer arround will love to help you..but i suggest for that you should start a new question so other people having more knowledge and exp. then me can teach you. and i also suggest TRY SOMETHING and then post Your problem,cause SO is Q/A Site not SPoon Feeding Site.If you just google arround with your issues your many doubt will be cleared.

Comment: i have posted the segment of code for what i use to get data from webservice

Comment: As a first starting point for android questions I would always take a look at the official developer page, with a lot of useful information and tutorials: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on the architecture of your app. If this data does not change, then you just might download it on first start and then reuse it.
2. Device cache? I know of no such thing. Normally complex data is stored in database. But this really depends on the type of data and access requirements you have (searching, etc..). See all [data storage options on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: thanx for replying peter bt can you please guide me how to store the data i got from webservice in the sqlite db

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the kind of data your storing, I would use one or the other. For caching binary data I use the file system ("device cache" as you say), but for more complex structures I prefer to use SQLite DB. An advantage of SQLite is, that you can alter your structure with every update easily using well known SQL Queries.

Oh @Frankenstein, was faster than me :D
EDIT: If you plan to cache categories and product collections I would always use a SQLite DB!

If the media files are static, you can even ship them with your application resources. In case  they are never changing.